# Batch Script - (Stop services, move log files to other directory, append date once move)

Tags: date, batch-file, scripting, append, move

I'm a newbie in batch scripting. How can i add a currentdate on the filename once i move the files to other directory? Can you please check my code below? Thanks!

This is how it works:

-- I need to copy some files to other directory in order to kill the running processes which are (dsst)
-- once the dsst is not running, it should stop the GESWCPAServer and delete the copied files in c:temp
-- Next, copy the logfiles from C:\LOGFILES to C:\LOGFILES\Archive.
-- after the files has been copied. it will now start the services.

Thanks!

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
@ECHO off 
copy D:\fp_swenv\cg_fp\config\*.magik c:\temp

sc stop GESWCPAServer

:loop
echo checking for task list
tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq dsst_writer_acp.exe" | find /I "dsst_writer_acp.exe"
rem tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq textpad.exe" | find /I "textpad.exe"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto sleeploop
goto finish_up

:sleeploop
echo Sleeping 10secs
sleep 10
goto loop

:finish_up
del c:\temp\*.magik
sc stop GESWDisptcher51
sc stop GESWCPAClient

sleep 10

set logpath1="C:\LOGFILES"
set arcpath1="C:\LOGFILES\Archive"

c:
cd %logpath1%
FORFILES /D -1 /M *.log /C "cmd /c move @path %arcpath1%"
cd /D %arcpath1%

sc start GESWCPAServer

sleep 10

echo checking for task list
tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq dsst_writer_acp.exe" | find /I "dsst_writer_acp.exe"
rem tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq textpad.exe" | find /I "textpad.exe"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto sleeploop

sc start GESWDisptcher51
sc start GESWCPAClient

@ECHO ON
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this works -

Replace your below code with my code.

```
set logpath1="C:\LOGFILES"
set arcpath1="C:\LOGFILES\Archive"

c:
cd %logpath1%
FORFILES /D -1 /M *.log /C "cmd /c move @path %arcpath1%"
```

My Code -

EDIT - Added the zip option as requested by OP in the comment.

```
@echo OFF

set logpath1=c:\Logfiles
set arcpath1=c:\Logfiles\archive

cd /d %logpath1%

for /f %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^| findstr /b [0-9]') do set TS=%%x

set yyyy=%TS:~0,4%
set mm=%TS:~4,2%
set dd=%TS:~6,2%
set hh=%TS:~8,2%
set min=%TS:~10,2%
set timestamp=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%_%hh%-%min%

for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.log') do call :moveandrename "%%i"
goto :jump

:moveandrename

set filename=%~n1
set fileextn=%~x1

move /y %filename%%fileextn% %arcpath1%\%filename%-%timestamp%%fileextn% >nul 2>&1
goto :eof


:jump

cd %arcpath1%
C:\Program Files\WinZip\wzzip.exe -a Archive_%timestamp%.zip *.log
if not %errorlevel% EQU 0 echo.Zip operation failed on %timestamp% >>zipresult.txt & goto :eof
del *.log


:eof
```

Cheers, G

Comment: I've added the above answer before you corrected the formatting. Could you let me know if you are looking to move the log files from C:\LOGFILES to C:\LOGFILES\Archive, but with the names appeneded with date?

Comment: Thanks! Yes that's right, i need to move the files from C:\LOGFILES to C:\LOGFILES\Archive. The files that needs to move are cpaclient.log,cpaserver.log and circuitservice.log and the names should be appended with date once move.

Comment: oh great!! it works!! Thanks a lot! :) One more thing, i want to zip the file once i move to other directory. do you have any code for that?

Comment: Yes, Could do. Which Zip program do you use? Do you want to zip all the files which are moved to new place(archive)? where do you want to keep the zip file?

Comment: we are using winzip program.Yes i want to zip all the files.  i want to keep the zip files to c:\Logfiles\Archive

Comment: @smashmeoff, Done. Added the zip operation now. After the file move, it will zip the log files with the name Archive_%timestamp%.zip and if the zip opeartion is successful, it will delete the log files. For any reason if the zip operation is failed, it will make an entry in a log file and won't delete the log files.

Comment: Awesome!It is now working. Thanks for the help, gbabu! Appreciate it!

Comment: Great, Glad I could help. If its working you could choose this as an answer!

Comment: Hey gbabu, I think the zip part is not working. i've installed the 7zip and its not working. Also tried the winzip app. same issue.

Comment: the error in the command prompt says that the C:\Program Files is not recognize as an external or internal command

Comment: Replace `C:\Program Files\WinZip\wzzip.exe -a Archive_%timestamp%.zip *.log` with this `"C:\Program Files\WinZip\wzzip.exe" -a Archive_%timestamp%.zip *.log`. Notice the double quotes symbol around  `C:\Program Files\WinZip\wzzip.exe`

Comment: Still not working.. i think the space is the issue in Program Files